# I have a problem with ConfirmButtonExtender in ASP.NET WEB FORM

Tags: asp.net, confirm

I have a table with patient data, and I also have a column with a delete button. This delete button has a ConfirmButtonExtender. The problem is that ConfirmButtonExtender only works on the first row and does not work on the rest of the rows.

```
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

            <!-- Start Table -->
            <table class="table table-dark">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">ID</th>
                        <th scope="col">FullName</th>
                        <th scope="col">Phone</th>
                        <th scope="col">BirthDay</th>
                        <th scope="col"></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemCommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand1">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FullName") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblPhone" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("phone") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("birthDay") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:LinkButton CssClass="btn btn-danger" ID="btnSelect" runat="server" CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<% #Eval("id")%>'> Select</asp:LinkButton>
                                    <asp:LinkButton CssClass="btn btn-danger" ID="btnDelete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument='<% #Eval("id")%>'>Delete</asp:LinkButton>
                                    <ajaxToolkit:ConfirmButtonExtender runat="server" ConfirmText="" BehaviorID="btnDelete_ConfirmButtonExtender" TargetControlID="btnDelete" ID="btnDelete_ConfirmButtonExtender"></ajaxToolkit:ConfirmButtonExtender>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>

                </tbody>
            </table>
            <!-- End Table -->
```

code C#

```
        protected void Repeater1_ItemCommand1(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
        {

            if(e.CommandName == "Delete")
            {
                string id = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
                int idPatient = Convert.ToInt32(id);
                Model1 model = new Model1();
                var patint = model.Patients.Find(idPatient);
                model.Patients.Remove(patint);
                model.SaveChanges();
                clearInput();
                Page_Load(source, e);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to the problem, just remove the BehaviorID property from ajaxToolkit:ConfirmButtonExtender